# Folder does not get created

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I am trying to create a new directory usingC#/asp.net webforms but I do not seem to have any luck.Here is my code:

```
    string path = "~/Images/avatar/" + User.Identity.Name + "/userAvatars/";
     private void createPath(string path)
     {
           string activeDir = @"~/Images/avatar/userAvatars";
           if( !Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(path)) )
           {
               string newPath = Path.Combine(activeDir, User.Identity.Name);
               Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);
            }
      }
     createPath(path)
```

Now this code does not throw any errors but it does not create the folder either unless I provide a physical directory starting from the letter of the drive.Example:

```
D:\Projects IDE\Visual Studio\MyWork\Websites\Forum
```

This won't work because at some point I will want to upload the application to the server.

So how can I set the filepath to get the root if the project and make this code work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
string newPath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(Path.Combine(activeDir, User.Identity.Name)
Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);
```

You are forgetting to map the newPath after you use Path.Combine.

Comment: You're welcome. Also just a note, Server.MapPath only works when HttpContext.Current is accessible where HostingEnvironment.MapPath will always work which is why the latter is preferred. In the future if you ever migrated to MVC or self-hosted without IIS then you would not have to make changes in that respect.

Answer (score 0):

you should make

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(newPath));
```